# Highcharts legend for left and right axis separated

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any way to show to which axis each series belong?

My boss is expecting to see two legends: One to the left and the other to the right, containing the corresponding series.

I tried formatting the series but legend doesn't accept markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unforutantley two legends are not avaiable, but you can prepare your own legend (in HTML) and use show/hide functions on legend:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.show()